# Prove or disprove: For all x, ((for all e>0, |x|<=e) implies that x=0)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, notation

I'm a little confused on how to prove or disprove this statement:

$$
\forall x \in R, ((\forall \epsilon >0, |x| \leq \epsilon ) \implies x=0)
$$

I'm pretty sure that the negation is given by

$$
∃x∈R,((∀e>0,|x|≤\epsilon),x≠0)
$$

But past that, can a single counter example disprove the negation? (and therefore prove the original proposition?)

Comment: you can say that $|x|\leq\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. And then $|x|$ is less than or equal to $inf(\frac{1}{n})=0$, so $|x|=0$

Comment: if $x$ was not $0$, then $|x|>0$. Take $\epsilon = \dfrac{|x|}2$ and plug in your statement to see what happens. Please correct your title, to match your question, you have x>=e in the title, and x<=e in the question.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a little bit? I'm still somewhat confused

Answer (score 3):

Another proof: Let $x\ne 0$. Then, $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $|x|=\epsilon$. Now choose $\delta=\epsilon/2$, then, $|x|>\delta$ which is a contradiction to the assumption.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Do you mind explaining (or linking) how delta statements work?

Comment: That's a standard trick in real analysis, basically it hinges on the simple observation (which can be proven by [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)) that if $a$ is a positive number then we can always find a positive number $b$ such that $0<b<a$

Answer (score 0):

Let and $x$ be given and suppose that $|x| \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. We must show that $x=0$. Taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ we find $|x| \leq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \epsilon = 0$.
Thus $|x| = 0$ and hence $x=0$.